# Установка Node.js в Ubuntu 16.04 - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

Подскажите как установить в Ubuntu 16.04 свежие версии NPM и Node.js. А то в репах 4.2 версия а на сайте сейчас уже 8.11. Вся инфа, которую нашел уже устарела. Когда устанавливаю через PPA Ubunta пишет что команда curl не действительна/устарела no

Comment: Ну так обновите/установите curl. А инфу по установке самого node.js, искать особо не нужно: она есть в официальной документации... там всего две команды (и еще одна для установки тулчейна) - кстати, дополните вопрос выводом этих команд.

Comment: В репах убунты 18.04 кстати **почти** самая свежая - 8.10

Comment: я бы посоветовал через nvm ставить.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -i

echo -e '\n \e[1;36m' Добавляется репозиторий NodeJS '\e[0m \n'

wget -q -O - https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -

VERSION="node_8.x"
DISTRO="$(lsb_release -s -c)"
echo "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/$VERSION $DISTRO main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
echo "deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/$VERSION $DISTRO main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list

apt update
```

[src](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)

Answer (score 1):

Есть [официальная инструкция](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) для этого:

```
sudo apt-get update -qq && sudo apt-get install -y curl 
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Если нужно, что-то тестировать на разных версиях можно [использовать docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/).

Для управления установкой есть также утилиты типа [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo npm i -g n
sudo n stable или latest или 8.11 или т.д
sudo npm i -g npm@latest
```